# Blazor Web App (.net 8 server) - Razor Component Library RCL as NuGet (Local Feed) w MainLayout style sharing

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, msbuild, blazor, nuget-package

**Updated after finding answer for future reference of those with issue**

What I was trying to do:

Use MainLayout on my webapp to make use of the RCL's razor component to pass in a navmenu and use the shared libraries styling etc.

I have a RCL that contains 2 razor components 'NavMenu.razor' and 'SharedLayout.razor'.

So any new team can bring in the nuget package and work with the default mainlayout styling component we determine. (later to add in a shared IdentityService).

**TLDR** : Answered on Reddit kept here for others with some edits for clarity and expediency.

**The problem was that I had included a tag that explicitly caused the NuGet to generate razor files and place them into the project that added the NuGet, causing all manner of issues with naming conflicts and lack of references.**

This is what my project looks like when referenced :
[image: Working Project Reference to RCL]

The code works in this setup, just to share quickly what's going on with it for context:
[image: Routes file references this MainLayout.razor as the default layout]

This looks like this when loaded:
[image: Working with proj ref]

## What I was Stuck on - as NuGet

However for the next step I wanted to create a NuGet to share the RCL across projects.
So I setup the RCL project file like this:

[image: proj file for the RCL]

The Example Server project I marked as false.

** note the tag in the project calling for  'includeRazorContentInPack' this was the problem**

[image: building the nuget]

Then push to a local feed nuget location.
[image: push to local feed]

I can then reference this nuget source from another project:
[image: Nuget local feed with package]

## Solution Structure with Nuget:

[image: What my solution looks like after bringing in the Nuget]

It placed the NuGets razor files in the solution. (resolved after moving tag)

## Problems:

*I have not edited the below problem section from when written. for fix see answer comment.*

**Log File - Proj Reload** (resolved? via clean)
Right away I was having issues with Visual Studio telling me that there was an unexpected problem loading of my project.

[image: On bringing in the NuGet]

By mucking around with _import and fully declaring components I can get this error to clear.
Deleting .vs bin obj...

The log file talks about an issue with Base path:
*I can provide the full log if anyone thinks it'll help.*

[image: log for project load failure]

**Multiple Components Named the same.**

When I brought in the nuget I received a multiple components using same tag error for both the SharedLayout and the NavMenu from the RCL NuGet.
[image: webapp mainlayout componentref]

I added in a @ using statement to the _Import.razor of the NuGet to reference the components. Which wasn't needed when using the proj ref as they were in the same namespace.

[image: _import razor of RCL using statement]

I also explicitly referenced the NavMenu component in the SharedLayout.razor file.

[image: shared layout in RCL explicit ref but failure?]

In the MainLayout of the actual webapp I fully referenced the SharedLayout... all these seemed to clear up this error.

[image: mainlayout on WebApp explicit]

I'd rather find a different way to handle this error. As there is only 1 component of that name, so the error's a bit strange, like it's duplicating components into namespace.

**No Errors but failure**

A mix of me referencing components in the RCL before producing as a nuget allowed it to build with no errors. But It's obviously failed to load correctly. Is this still something I've gotten wrong with working with a RCL NuGet or is this some incompatibility to send @ body to a Nuget?

[image: failure on run with no errors]

I was expecting to be able to bring in a NuGet package that contained a Razor Component, and pass in parameters and values into the components. Including the body render fragment.

To use the NuGets Styling sheet (not included in this example as failure occurred before this attempt). To allow for a consistent look across any app that uses the sharedlayout component.

Allowing dynamic Nav by passing in the items to display.(as shown in the MainLayout.razor file and working as shown in proj example picture).

To work as it did when referencing a project.

Answer (score 0):

Reddit came to the rescue with an observation that I'd included the IncludeRazorContentInPack in my package build. I did this following some info I found on the topic for building these class libraries as NuGets and obviously that was the wrong move for what I was hoping to achieve.

Comment: [Polite] Are you answering your own question or not?  I'm not sure.  If so then why not just delete the question.  It's a wall of images, with a comment that may or may not be an answer.  In it's current format, it's not a question and answer that adds anything to SO.  Or does "I can't figure out how to bring in as a nuget and actually get it to work as expected." still stand?

Comment: Thanks for marking as polite for context.  So I could not find the issue when I was searching. I looked at other posts and came up empty. I made an answer response myself as the issue was as someone on Reddit told me (remove that tag that explicitly creates in proj razor files). I thought I'd keep to hopefully assist anyone else with same issue. I can edit my initial post for clarity.

Comment: I prefer to provide feedback rather that just hitting the close and/or downgrade buttons.  You don't need to do anything if you don't want to, you have an answer.  Without some useful clicks, your question and answer will fall into the masses that aren't deemed particularly useful by the SO Bots.